# Installing WCF Service using WIX installer

Tags: c#, wcf, wix, installation, wcf-data-services

What is did is;

1. Created a WCF service library project.
2. Then I created a host application that starts the service. Now when I double click the executable, the service gets started.
3. Then I added a WIX project and added the required components

Wix code:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="ServiceComp" Guid="{4A6E2246-50E1-4D1B-937F-B01669E48641}">
        <File Id="Service.dll" Name="Service.dll" Source="..\ServiceHost\bin\Debug\Service.dll"/>
        <File Id="ServiceHost.exe" Name="ServiceHost.exe" Source="..\ServiceHost\bin\Debug\ServiceHost.exe"/>
        <File Id="ServiceHost.exe.config" Name="ServiceHost.exe.config" Source="..\ServiceHost\bin\Debug\ServiceHost.exe.config"/>
        <ServiceInstall Id="MYServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Name="MYService" DisplayName=" MYSStartService " Description="MY Service Component" Start="auto" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="critical" />
        <ServiceControl Id="MYSStartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="MYService" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
```

Now when I run the setup, it generates an error

[image]

Also I tried the following,

- I added a windows service project
- Referenced the Service project(referenced the dll file).
- Added Installers (Process, Service) and configured them.
- And then did the same in wix.

Still I am getting the same problem.

Now my questions are:

- Where should I place `<ServiceInstall>` and `<ServiceControl>` tags in WiX file? (Should they be in the component block where the executable is located or anywhere?)
- What might causing the problem during installation?
- How can I create a WiX setup file for a WCFLibrary project?
- Have I missed any things that need to be included?

Please assist me.

Here is the code of Windows form application that is starting and stopping the service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceModel;


namespace ServiceWinHost
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool started = false;
        internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!started)
                Start();
            else
                Stop();
        }

        void Start() {
            try
            {
                if (myServiceHost != null)
                {
                    myServiceHost.Close();
                }
                myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service.Service1));
                myServiceHost.Open();

                label1.Text = "Started....";
                started = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                label1.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }

        void Stop() {

        try
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
                myServiceHost = null;
            }
            started = false;
            label1.Text = "Stopped....";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

The wix file complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="ServiceWinSetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Service Host" UpgradeCode="b9c11d77-b587-4f24-ba49-3a4031a35652">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <!--<MediaTemplate />-->

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="ServiceWinSetup" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" CompressionLevel="high" />
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="ServiceWinSetup" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="ServiceComp" Guid="{4A6E2246-50E1-4D1B-937F-B01669E48641}">
        <File Id="Service.dll" Name="Service.dll" Source="..\ServiceWinInstall\bin\Debug\Service.dll"/>
        <File Id="ServiceWinInstall.exe" Name="ServiceWinInstall.exe" Source="..\ServiceWinInstall\bin\Debug\ServiceWinInstall.exe"/>
        <File Id="ServiceWinInstall.exe.config" Name="ServiceWinInstall.exe.config" Source="..\ServiceWinInstall\bin\Debug\ServiceWinInstall.exe.config"/>
        <ServiceInstall Id="MYSERVICE" Type="ownProcess" Name="MyService" DisplayName="My own ervice" Description="just for test" Start="auto" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="critical" />
        <ServiceControl Id="MYSERVICEStartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="MyService" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

and, my service project, hosting project and setup project are under same solution but different projects

[image]

Comment: A Windows service is completely different from a WCF service. Have you inherited from `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase` and implemented the `OnStart` and `OnStop` methods in your executable?

Comment: No.i have a windows form application. there i have created my own start and stop methods which are triggered by button.Here is my code:
        bool started = false;
        internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null; 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!started)
                Start();
            else
                Stop();
        }

Comment: void Start() {
                if (myServiceHost != null)
                {
                    myServiceHost.Close();
                }
                myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service.Service1));
                myServiceHost.Open();

                label1.Text = "Started....";
                started = true;
            }
        }
        void Stop() {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
                myServiceHost = null;
            }
            started = false;
            label1.Text = "Stopped....";
        }

Comment: Don't put the code in a comment. Edit the question and add the code.